# Good software to view windows?

Tags: windows

I am trying to locate the handle of a button in a application to send a message to it so i want a good window finder that can get the window from the cursor . I am not trying to code such a tool i want only a name of an app i can download.Thanks.

Comment: What is a window finder? I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Winspector Spy.  Sadly, their site is down, but a cached installer is [here](http://www.autohotkey.net/~goyyah/Winspector_setupU.exe).

Other solutions are also listed [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/wiki/index.php?title=Spy_software).

Answer (score 2):

Spy++ should do that for you. It's included in the Visual Studio tools.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe